# Не получается соединить два поля из таблиц БД

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Дурацкий вопрос наверное, но не могу соединить два поля. Не понимаю, почему возникает ошибка.

[image: Возникает вот такая ошибка]e.png

[image: Это те поля, которые я хочу соединить]

Comment: ну тут просто у вас в таблице есть в изменяемом поле ключ который ссылаеться на объект в другой таблице. А в ней уже есть данные

Comment: Суть проблемы в том, что в таблице на стороне "много" (`question`) имеются записи, у которых для значения реферального поля `id_test` нет соответствующего значения в таблице на стороне "один" (`test`). Ну это при условии, что нет более дурацких причин - вроде несовпадения типа, длины, NULL-овости и т.п.